# Move item in RecyclerView to another position

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a list of items in a RecyclerView which gets populated from a Firebase Database. I'd like to implement movement of items inside the RecyclerView by long press and dragging. (Similar to Google's note app "Keep")

I have already seen some other similar questions but I was not able to find any solution which suits my needs.

Following some code examples.

**MainActivity** (onCreate)

```
 mRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);



    mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mManager.setReverseLayout(false);
    mManager.setStackFromEnd(false);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);


    findViewById(R.id.fab_new_post).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(RecordActivity.this, NewRecordActivity.class));
        }
    });

    // Set up FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with the Query

    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Record, RecordViewHolder>(Record.class, R.layout.item_record, RecordViewHolder.class, mDatabase.child("user-record").child(getUid())) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final RecordViewHolder viewHolder, final Record model, final int position) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

            // Set click listener for the whole post view
            final String postKey = postRef.getKey();
            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Launch RecordDetailActivity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecordDetailActivity.class);

                    //MANDARE TESTO A POSTDETAILACTIVITY
                    intent.putExtra(RecordDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postKey);
                    intent.putExtra(RecordDetailActivity.TITLE, model.title);
                    intent.putExtra(RecordDetailActivity.BODY, model.body);
                    intent.putExtra(RecordDetailActivity.DATE, model.date);
                    intent.putExtra(RecordDetailActivity.NOTE, model.note);
                    intent.putExtra(RecordDetailActivity.COLOR, model.color);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            // Bind Record to ViewHolder, setting OnClickListener for the star button

            viewHolder.bindToPost( model);
```

**RecordViewHolder**

```
public class RecordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView titleView;
public TextView bodyView;
public TextView dateView;
public TextView noteView;
public TextView colorView;
public CardView cardView;


public RecordViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    titleView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
    bodyView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_body);
    dateView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.record_item_date);
    noteView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.record_item_note);
    colorView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.record_item_color);
    cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.record_item_card);
}

public void bindToPost(Record record) {
    titleView.setText(record.title);
    bodyView.setText(record.body);
    dateView.setText(record.date);
    noteView.setText(record.note);
    colorView.setText(record.color);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using FirebaseUI's `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, the data will be shown in the order in which you retrieve it from the database.

That means to re-order the data, you will need to either create a new query *or* add a property to your data that you can use to set the order. A common way to do the latter is to add an `index` property to your records. Then when the user drags a record to a different position, you'll "just" have to update the index of all affected records.

Comment: ahh ok! I understand what you mean! But I do not know how to do what you said. if you could help me with a small example would be great! (If i don't disturb)

Comment: Frank is `index` is a good way or is there a better way then adding `index` property in records.